# How to check if a firebase timestamp is greater than current date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to compare a timestamp field with the current date in javascript.

I tryed like this:

```
let myDocs = [];
await getDocs( collection( database, 'myCollection' ) ).then( ( documents ) => {
    documents.docs.forEach( ( document ) => {
        if(document.data().createdAt < new Date() ){
            myDocs.push({ id:document.id, ...document.data() });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-modular-api), like this:

```
getDocs(
  query(
    collection(database, 'myCollection'),
    where('createdAt', '<=', new Date)
  )
).then( ( documents ) => {
  ...
})
```

Now only the documents that match your criteria will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: Ok, that may be helpful, but, i'm sorry for not being more specific. I want to hace separated in other array those results that doesn't match with the date condition.

let myDocs = [];
let draft = []
await getDocs( collection( database, 'myCollection' ) ).then( ( documents ) => {
    documents.docs.forEach( ( document ) => {
        if(document.data().createdAt < new Date() ){
            myDocs.push({ id:document.id, ...document.data() });
        }else{
            draft.push({ id: document.id, ...document.data() });
        }
    });
});


¿Would you recomend 2 queries?

Comment: @JuanDiegoLunaCazares If your original question didn't contain enough information, then you should edit it to be complete - don't leave information in comments (especially not code) that others might miss in the future.  If you have a new question that's different than your original question, you should post that separately.